# How can I make float numbers display -0 also as 0?

Tags: c++

If I divide a float 0 by a negative value I get displayed -0 which is inconvenient. How can I get rid of this issue?

```
float a = 0;
std::cout << a / (-1);
```

I've tried to check if a number is equal with -0 and if that condition were true, to multiply the variable by -1. This doesn't work because 0 is equal to -0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writing `a + 0.0f` gets rid of the signed zero for a `float` type `a`.

(This is defined by IEEE754 and is a standard trick well-known to numericists.)

So if you have an expression that might yield a signed zero, append `0.0f` to the end:

```
std::cout << a / (-1) + 0.0f;
```